# Does precision damage affect incorporeal creatures?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage, incorporeal

Does precision damage affect incorporeal creatures?  If so, does it affect them fully, or based on how the effect would attack them (50% for magic weapons, and 100% for Ghost Touch weapons)?

For example:

A rogue flanks a ghost with a fighter.  He's using a +1 dagger, and deals +2d6 sneak attack.  He hits.  Which of the following occurs (or some other result)?

- (1d4+1)/2
- (1d4+1 + 2d6) /2
- (1d4+1)/2 + 2d6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rules for the Incorporeal subtype mention precision damage specifically:

> An incorporeal creature is immune to critical hits and precision-based damage (such as sneak attack damage) unless the attacks are made using a weapon with the ghost touch special weapon quality.

Taken from [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Incorporeal).  If you don't have a Ghost Touch weapon, then the damage the ghost would take would be (1d4+1)/2.  If you do, it would be the full 1d4+1 + 2d6.

Answer (score 8):

A creature with the [incorporeal subtype](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/monsters/creatureTypes.html#incorporeal-subtype) is immune to precision damage, except from ghost touch weapons.

However, it's possible to be incorporeal without gaining the incorporeal subtype, such as by the spell *[dust form](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCombat/spells/dustForm.html#_dust-form)*. In that case, an creature attacked without a ghost touch weapon would be vulnerable to precision damage, but the total damage dealt by the attack would still be halved as normal.