# Is Sneak Attack damage halved on a successful Will save if a Wand of Cure Light Wounds is used to trigger the Sneak Attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, rogue, saving-throw, sneak-attack

Suppose, a Rogue with Use Magic Device wants to attack an Undead, perhaps an Incorporeal one. [They can use a Wand of Cure Light Wounds for that](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/45525/30214) since it does require an attack roll. The Rogue somehow gets their Sneak Attack: the Undead is flat-footed, flanked, or something like that.

Now, the said Undead successfully makes their Will save and only takes (1d8)/2 damage, instead of just 1d8.

**Is the Sneak Attack damage also halved?**

**Will an Incorporeal Undead halve the damage one more time because the Rogue is not incorporeal?**

Comment: related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/12935/9078

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### An incorporeal creature would be immune to the Sneak Attack dice.

The [Incorporeal Subtype](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/Creature-types/#Incorporeal_Subtype) includes immunity to Precision damage except, specifically, when delivered with a Ghost Touch weapon; Sneak Attack is precision damage regardless of the type of damage it's amplifying.

You *may* be able to get around this with a *ghost touch amulet of mighty fists*; ask your GM if that's worth the investment to you. This is assuming that using a wand is allowing *yourself* to cast Cure Wounds, meaning you perform the Touch Attack with your hand, not the wand.

### If the Rogue were to Cure Wounds Sneak Attack another type of Undead, such as a Zombie (because their Rapier isn't quite *cutting it*), it's a little less clear.

The best use-case comparison leans toward the Sneak Attack damage also being halved. To me, this is based on the [Arcane Trickster](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/core-rulebook/arcane-trickster/#TOC-Surprise-Spells) capstone ability, Surprise Spells

> At 10th level, an arcane trickster can add her sneak attack damage to any spell that deals damage, if the targets are flat-footed. This additional damage only applies to spells that deal hit point damage, and the additional damage is of the same type as the spell. **If the spell allows a saving throw to negate or halve the damage, it also negates or halves the sneak attack damage.**

However, as with anything not written out explicitly, you'll have to ask your GM how they would rule.